# use of 0xFF and keyWait(1) in OpenCV python

Tags: python-3.x

```
while(True):
   img,frame=cap.read()
   cv.imshow("preview",frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
       break
```

The above is a snippet of my python OpenCV program for accessing camera.
can anyone explain that how the loop ends when i press the character "q" in keyboard and why is 0xFF is used?

Answer (score 0):

According to openCV docs on the waitKey function,

> it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time. It **returns the code of the pressed key** or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

`0xFF` is hexadecimal, which converts to `11111111` in binary.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator

This means that `0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)` essentially returns the last 8 bits of the value returned by `cv2.waitKey()`. Since the waitKey funtion returns the code of the pressed key, it is the last 8 bits of the key which was pressed.

i.e if the key pressed is equal to 'q', break the loop